# UIImage view resets after animation is called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, caanimation

Im new to core animation. Every time I call the animation my image moves from its location to the top left of the screen, moves, then goes back to the original location. How do I make the image move 50 units left, stop, then repeat if the button is pressed again.
Code:

```
-(IBAction)preform:(id)sender{

CGPoint point = CGPointMake(50, 50);

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.fromValue  = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
anim.toValue    = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(point.x + 50, point.y)];
anim.duration   = 1.5f;
anim.repeatCount =1;
anim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
[imView.layer  addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you can skip heavy CA machinery and use block animations

```
// Your image is at starting position
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset(imView.frame, 50, 0);
        imView.frame = newFrame;
    }];
```

But, if you want to know how to handle this "snap back" correctly, check [this url](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/11/prevent-caanimation-snap-back/).